# Oracle: Can you grant CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE specifically?

Tags: oracle

Can you grant privilege to allows the creation of a global temporary table ONLY, i.e. without CREATE TABLE?

The background of this stems from security models that don't allow 'CREATE TABLE'... I can't find a reference to any specific privileges.

Comment: Just out of interest, why do you need a global temporary table?

Comment: The story as a whole is not worth telling, but the premise is that the table allows temporary data storage with a guarantee to retain no sensitive data.

Comment: Thanks! I asked because the usage pattern of temporary tables in Oracle is different than in other databases. I would normally create on temp table in the application schema and grant users to *use* it. The end users do not normally create and drop their own temporary tables...

Comment: That is what I have known to be the standard, agreed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I can't find a reference to any specific privileges.

Because, as far as I know, there is none. You'll still have to grant `CREATE TABLE` privilege to a user so he could create `TEMPORARY` tables.

In order to prevent a user from creating regular tables, and allow him to create only temporary tables you might consider the following:

Grant `CREATE TABLE` privilege to a user and revoke quota on a specific tablespace.

```
alter user <<user_name>> quota 0M on <<tablespace>>;
```

It might be the user's default tablespace or a different one.

In Oracle's versions with no `DEFFERED_SEGMENT_CREATION` it'll be enough for the user to see `space quota exceeded for tablespace` when he/she tries to create a regular table.

In Oracle's version with `DEFFERED_SEGMENT_CREATION` a user will still be able to create regular tables, but will not be able populate them. The second the user tries to execute an `INSERT` statement the `space quota exceeded for tablespace` appears.

So you might consider setting `deferred_segment_creation` parameter to `false`.

```
alter system set deferred_segment_creation = false;
```